# Laravel: How to use session in the whole app?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I want use session in Laravel like  `$_SESSION['test']`  in a normal PHP.

I tried this in Laravel, but the data is not stored when I use the session in another Controller.

// User CONTROLLER

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function testSession(Request  $request)
    {
       // ...
    Session::set( 'id','1' );
    $request->session()->put('username', 'simo');

    }
}
```

Another CONTROLLER

```
class AnotherController extends Controller
{
    public function GetMySession(Request  $request)
    {
       // ...
    dd($request->session()->all());// 

    }
}
```

Now username and id are not stored in the Session. Why?

Comment: Are both routes in the `routes/web.php`? Or is one an API route?

Comment: Have you reviewed your config/session.php ? Also check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session link for more info.

Comment: Now it works when i use session::save() after $request->session()->put('username', 'simo'); and data is stored in the session

Comment: try using global `session()` rather then `$request->session`

Answer (score 0):

In laravel,To use sessions `use Session;`

When you want to set a session use set() method as -

```
Session::set('variableName', $value);
```

When you want to get any session then get it like this -

```
Session::get('variableName');
```

And if you want to reset it again then use put() method -

```
Session::put('variableName', $value);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: okay, but if you gonna use Session::set('variableName', $value);
 then you dont need session::save() method and you can get that session in entire project.